# Evaluating the contour integral $\int_{|z|=1}\dfrac{\tan\pi z}{z^{3}}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

As the title suggests, i am evaluating the contour integral $$\int_{|z|=1}\dfrac{\tan\pi z}{z^{3}}dz.$$

My steps are as follows:

$f(z)=\dfrac{\tan\pi z}{z^{3}}=\dfrac{\phi(z)}{z^{3}}$ has $z=0$ as a singular point. It is a pole of order 3.
By Cauchy's Residue Theorem,
$$\int_{|z|=1}f(z)=2\pi i.Res_{z=0}f(z)=2\pi i(\phi''(z))|_{z=0}= 2\pi i(0)=0 $$

(1) May i ask if this is a correct solution?

(2) Also, another possible solution is to express $f(z)=\dfrac{\sin\pi z}{z^{3}\cos\pi z}$. With that, we can easily see that aside from $z=0$, $z=(n+\frac{1}{2}), \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ are also singularities of the function. Due to this version of this soultion, i am now quite confused if my initial solution shown above is correct. The problem is that when i try to compute the residue, $Res_{z=n+\frac{1}{2}}f(z)$ will seem like a mess as there seems to be infinitely many $n+\frac{1}{2}$ to consider. For the second case if i had expressed $f(z)=\dfrac{\sin\pi z}{z^{3}\cos\pi z}$, will i still get$\int_{|z|=1}\dfrac{\tan\pi z}{z^{3}}dz=0$?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The singularities that are contained in $\left| z \right|  =1$ are $z = \frac{1}{2}, z = -\frac{1}{2}$ and $z = 0$. Calculate the residues at these points, add them up and multiply by $2\pi i$.

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for your help! Can you help me to verify if the reside i calculated at $z=0$ is indeed 0? Or should it be something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides $z=0$, you have to consider the singularities at $z = \pm 1/2$.  Not all $n + 1/2$, only the ones inside the contour.  By the way, the pole at $z=0$ has order $2$, not $3$, because $\tan(\pi z)$ has a simple zero at $z=0$.

You might also note that $\tan(\pi z)/z^3$ is an even function, so by symmetry 
$\oint_\Gamma f(z)\; dz = 0$ for any contour $\Gamma$ that is invariant under the reflection $z \to -z$.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your comment. May i ask did i calculate the residue at $z=0$ shown above correctly? That is, i am using the formula: If $f(z)= \dfrac{\phi (z)}{(z-z_{0})^{m}}$, then $Res_{z=z_{0}}f(z)=\dfrac{\phi ^{(m-1)} (z_{0}) }{(m-1)!}$. So, if $z=0$ is order 2 which you pointed out, should $m=2$ in this case? Thanks!

Comment: In this case $\phi(z) = \tan(\pi z)/z$ (with singularity at $0$ removed).  But it's simpler to use a few terms of the Maclaurin series of $\tan$.

Comment: Thank you so much! $\phi (z)$ was the function i just couldn't figure out. Will try it out. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

For $f(z)=\dfrac{\tan\pi z}{z^{3}}$ we have a pole at $z=0$ of order $2$ and two simple poles $z=\pm\dfrac12$ which lie inside $|z|=1$. Then with
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\tan\pi z}{z^{3}}
&= \dfrac{\pi}{z^2}\dfrac{\sin\pi z}{\pi z}\dfrac{1}{\cos \pi z} \\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{z^2}\left(1-\dfrac{(\pi z)^2}{3!}+\dfrac{(\pi z)^4}{5!}-\dfrac{(\pi z)^6}{7!}+\cdots\right)/
\left(1-\dfrac{(\pi z)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{(\pi z)^4}{4!}-\dfrac{(\pi z)^6}{6!}+\cdots\right) \\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{z^2}+\dfrac{\pi^3}{3}+\dfrac{2\pi^5z^2}{15}+\cdots
\end{align}
we have
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}f(z)=0\\
&\operatorname{Res}_{z=\frac12}f(z)=-\dfrac{8}{\pi}\\
&\operatorname{Res}_{z=-\frac12}f(z)=\dfrac{8}{\pi}\\
\end{align}
so
$$\int_{|z|=1}\dfrac{\tan\pi z}{z^{3}}dz=2\pi i\sum \operatorname{Res}_{z=0,\pm\frac12}f(z)=0$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am unfamiliar with using the laurent series to obtain the residues as my classes emphasized on using formulas to compute the residue instead. Could you briefly explain how can we obtain the residues of $f(z)$ at $z=0,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}$? Thanks once again.

Comment: $\operatorname{Res}_{z=\frac12}f(z)=\lim_{z\to\frac12}(z-\dfrac12)\dfrac{\tan\pi z}{z^{3}}=-\dfrac{8}{\pi}$ Can you solve this limit?

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. Thanks once again.